# get key value pair from a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have the realation

```
private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> levelProgress;
 // LevelID -->[String][Progress]
```

I would like to get the key and value from only the first element in the nested dictionary(stored dictionary), but I need the dictionary that is from levelProgress[key] , only its first key, and its first value

```
 foreach (int key in levelProgress.Keys)
 {
     Dictionary<string, int> storedDictionary;
     if (levelProgress.TryGetValue(key, out storedDictionary))
     {

     }
 }
```

Comment: What problems are you currently having?

Comment: I just can't related the levelProgress dictionary with the nested one. I need for levelprogress[key] I need the relevant key, value from the nested dictionary, not all the keys and values from the nested one.

Comment: @Mahmoud : The problem is that dictionary is not sorted. So if you get the first from the inner dictionary the result might be different for every request

Comment: What do you mean first key: ordered by int? insertion order?...

Comment: @vc74 yes, the first key and it's related dictionary. it's related dictionary, I need its key and value, not all his keys, values

Comment: @Mahmoud can you explain why the first found key is necessary for you? As others mentioned already the inerts of a dictionary (or a list) are NOT sorted normally. Thus each time you run the program it could return a different value/key pair if you "just" go for the first found one. Thus the reason behind "first" or what exactly you mean with first would help greatly to find out what you need exactly

Comment: @Thomas, so I need to get the correct key from the first dictionary and the correct key, value from the nested one. but only one key, value from the nested one.

Comment: @Mahmoud can you modify the code so that we see variables which you want to use for the naming of the keys you want to get?  Also normally a dictionary should only have unique keys anyway. Does that mean in your case you have a dictionary that has non unique keys? (never saw a dictionary which is not unique tbh). also before I forget please also add in your post what framework version you are using as I just read 3 which would invalidate some possible answers

Comment: @Thomas the dictionary has unique keys, I modified the post.

Comment: @Mahmoud fyi if an answer is still incomplete and not what you are exactly looking for you should talk to the poster that it needs modification and only accept it after it is corrected as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to get the **first** key:

```
var innerDictKvp = levelProgress[key].First();
var key = innerDictKvp.Key; 
var value = innerDictKvp.Value;
```

However, you **cannot** predict what that key will be.
If you have the select key, you should fetch the value like:

```
var innerKey = "myKey";
var innerDictKvp = levelProgress[key].First(kvp => kvp.Key == innerKey);
var value = innerDictKvp.Value;
```

P.s. you should use `FirstOrDefault` if your not sure if the key exists.

**Edit:**
For older versions of .Net that don't support LINQ:

```
var innerDict = levelProgress[key];
IEnumerator enumerator = innerDict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext(); // Get first item
var firstKey = enumerator.Current as string;
var firstVal = (int)innerDict[firstKey];
```

Comment: +1 for the exclamation that one cannot predict what they key can be

Comment: @Amir It seems like the OP is on .net 3, he won't be able to use linq

Comment: @vc74 - I've updated my post to support older versions of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string secondDictionaryKey = "";
 string secondDictionaryValue = "";
 foreach (int key in levelProgress.Keys)
 {
     Dictionary<string, int> storedDictionary;
     if (!levelProgress.TryGetValue(key, out storedDictionary))
         continue;

     foreach(string k in storedDictionary.Keys)
     {
         secondDictionaryKey = k;
         secondDictionaryValue = storedDictionary[k];
         break;
     }

     break;               

 }
```

Comment: is it possible to get the relevant keypair value from the nested dictionary that is related/correlated to the relevant key

Comment: I just need to the get the keyvalue pair from the nested dictionary too, but related to it's equivalent key in the first dictionary.

Comment: @mybirthname from how I understand the comments given by the op there is a second key known thus he needs the dictionary from the first given key and from that dictionary the value of another given key.

Comment: @Thomas I don't understand what exactly he wants. What is wanted in the description is done first key value of the stored dictionary.

Comment: @mybirthname his comments contradict his post there. That is why I said from how I understand his comments.    Mahmoud can you clarify there ? or if it is correct as I assume from your comments taht you need really only specific keys each can you modify your original post to show this? (currently as I mentioned your comments are contradicting the original post which leads to some confusion)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to writ that in Linq by doing something along these lines

```
levelProgress.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Key == key).Value.FirstOrDefault().Key;
```